# Only one .ts file is generating while encoding mp3 file to m3u8 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, m3u8

I am not able to play m3u8 link for some specific files.

Details are as follows:

`ffmpeg  -i low_30.mp3 -codec:v libx264 -b:v  64k -maxrate 64k -bufsize 64k -vf  scale=-2:480 -threads 0 -vsync 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -b:a  64k  -hls_list_size 0 abc.m3u8`

Error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fc83280ba00] MB rate (81000000) > level limit (2073600)
[libx264 @ 0x7fc83280ba00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc83280ba00] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 5.2, 4:4:4 8-bit
[hls @ 0x7fc832809e00] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
```

Sample File URL: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/hog-original/low_30.mp3

Only one TS file is generating in this case and not able to play the m3u8 link.

Comment: Do you wish to keep the cover image in the segments?

Comment: No i don't want to keep cover image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i low_30.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -vn -hls_list_size 0 abc.m3u8
```

Default segment duration is 2 seconds. Add `-hls_time N` to create segments of N seconds.

Comment: I stumbled upon this post and would like to note that `-segment_time` does not seem to work with HLS (at least not in more recent versions of FFMPEG). However, `-hls_time N` is working.

Comment: Indeed, segment_time is for segment muxer

Comment: while conversion how to keep cover image ?